# Can you use an accesskey attribute on an option tag?

Tags: html, access-keys

Is there a technique to use an `accesskey` attribute on an `<option>` tag?

I know you can use it on a `<select>`, but I have a requirement to use it on an `<option>` **within** a `<select>`.

Example: I need to do something like this?

```
<select>
    <option>Blah</option>
    <option accesskey="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having an `accesskey` attribute on an `<option>` tag [doesn’t validate as HTML4](http://validator.w3.org/), but [does as HTML5](http://html5.validator.nu/).

I’ve made a [test case on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pauldwaite/sksGr/) — accesskey 9 is assigned to the text field, whilst accesskey 2 is assigned to the second `<option>` in the `<select>`.

Firefox 5 on the Mac doesn’t focus the `<option>` when you activate its accesskey (using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> — see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key#Access_in_different_browsers), but Chrome 12 does (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>).

Theoretically, you could write some JavaScript to listen for this specific key combination and set the `<select>`’s selected option, but I’m not sure if that’s worth it, or a good idea — it might confuse users more than anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your help Paul, I might need to use something like js-hotkeys.

Comment: js-hotkeys looks like the solution. Thanks again.

Comment: @duyker: aha, a pre-built JavaScript solution, that sounds good. You’re most welcome.